# How to use sprintf in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file

this is my code

```
for k = 1 : 5
im = imread(sprintf('C:\1\%d.BMP',k));

%blablalba...

end
```

There are 5 BMP files in "C: \ 1 \"

The files are named 1.BMP, 2.BMP, 3.BMP, 4.BMP, and 5.BMP respectively

Use sprintf to import files of 1.BMP, 2.BMP ... 5.BMP respectively into imread

But there is an error.

> error : demo_SR (line 5)
>
> im = imread(sprintf('C:\1\%d.BMP',k));

Why do I get an error when I get k from 1 to 5 and write"%d"?

thanks you

Comment: You showed *where* the error is, not *what* the error is.

Comment: Those two lines are all the error messages.

Comment: If that is the case you have a bad installation of MATLAB, but I really really doubt it. Or you are not showing everything that is relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
im = imread(sprintf('C:/1/%d.BMP',k));
```

MATLAB may interpret `\` as a command for escaped characters.

Comment: @ONION please consider going through all your questions and accepting the answers that helped you. Otherwise, people will stop answering your questions, as you are not following common courtesy

Answer (score 2):

For the reason mentioned in @Ander Biguri's answer, you should either use a double backslash,

```
filename = sprintf('C:\\1\\%d.BMP',k);
```

or, more robust would be to let MATLAB insert the appropriate path separator by using [fullfile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html),

```
filename = fullfile('C:','1',sprintf('%d.BMP',1));
```